# Noexcept equivilent in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, language-features

I want to ask is there in C# analogue for C++ "noexcept" attribute for methods which does not generate any exceptions. Something like that:

```
    public int SomeMethod() noexcept
    {
     throw new ArgumentNullException (); //Compile error: Method with 'noexcept' 
attribute can't generate exceptions.
    }
```

And when I want to call this method in my code I need not to think about try/catch block for this method.

Comment: I do not believe there is such a thing. You will have to try catch within your `SomeMethod`

Comment: I think there's a typo in the question, surely you mean 'noexcept'?

Comment: There's nothing built into the language itself, you'd need to use a static analysis tool to enforce this kind of convention..

Comment: @MattDavey Might this be a use case for Roslyn? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/10/19/the-roslyn-preview-is-now-available.aspx

Comment: @Oskar certainly! I think once Roselyn matures we'll have a flood of really cool new static analysis tools :)

Comment: There will never be exception specifications in the C# language, Anders will make sure of that.  They are deprecated in the new C++ language specification.

Answer (score 4):

So far as I know, there is nothing like that in C# (though I'm not 100% on that). With regards to it's use; when writing clean code you should only handle exceptions as and where you expect them to occur. This allows for the flow and control of your program to be much more manageable.

If you are unaware of an exception that could occur during a method, or an exception occurs that you did not expect, then you need to determine whether that exception is something that is considered critical (in that it *should* cause the application to fail); or whether it should be specifically handled within the code.

Comment: I wish more people got the idea of "if there's something you didn't expect happening, crashing might very well be the best thing to do". If you want to avoid that, just make sure all your "blank" `try ... catch` statements only ever occur in completely isolated code with no shared state with the rest of the application. Otherwise you're opening yourself up to very weird inconsistency bugs. I've debugged many such applications, and it's a royal pain.